# parse jsonld in python

Tags: python, json-ld

I'm trying to parse a big jsonld file in python. I use pyld lib.  The problem is that some data are empty, there is only a key like

```
{"@id": "data:0089c6e8-f891-37b2-90cb-f833741e45ab"}
```

The data associated with this key is defined somewhere else in the file :

```
  {
  "@id": "data:0089c6e8-f891-37b2-90cb-f833741e45ab",
  "schema:addressLocality": "Morganx",
  "schema:postalCode": "40700",
  "dc:hasAddressCity": {
    "@id": "kb:40198"
  },
```

OK this is a way to reduce size of the file but is this compliant with the jsonld standard ?

And is there a way (with pyld or other) to associate all the empty @id with their values without brute-force parsing all the file ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be better if you show some effort by producing an _attempt_ to solve the problem, in order to show some specific implementation issues you have encountered and to facilitate the help from the community.

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 yes but the first step is to know if my jsonld file is correct, if not I'll submit a bug to my data producer. If the behaviour I described is compliant to the standard i can go a step further. the step further is to see is there is a builtin function (pyld or python json ...) to re-associate keys with their data, for the moment I did not find such a function.

Comment: Without more details it's unclear what the problem is. From a data model view it's ok to refer to things elsewhere like it appears you are doing. You do have to "brute force" parse data to get the whole picture, but tools exist. If the data is very large, a RDF based database might help. If it's not too big, consider pre-processing your data with the embedding options of JSON-LD framing. The JS lib has "node map" support to help with id indexing but that may not be in pyld. Feel free to file issues with pyld or the specs if you have suggestions for ways to better handle this type of data.